# Implement ReportViewer with DXA

Tags: dxa

I have a project using DXA 2.0 I need to add some SSRS reports so used this solution :
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Display-SSRS-report-e3f6be05
Basically, its embeds ASPX form in IFRAME and it works fine but some reports have links, when I click the link I got an internal exception:

> ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart] - Setting
>   status code:500   ERROR
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestEnd]  An error occured
>   while the request was processed. OnRequestEnd will not be triggered! 
>   The thread 0x380c has exited with code 0 (0x0).  The thread 0x58e4 has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).  The thread 0xce4 has exited with code 0
>   (0x0).  The thread 0x6edc has exited with code 0 (0x0).  The thread
>   0x6ccc has exited with code 0 (0x0).  2018-10-12 13:22:44 ERROR
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart] - Problem 
>   EXCEPTION:  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. 
>   Parameter name: key  at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)  at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)  at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.SetWebRequestClaims(HttpRequest
>   request, IClaimStore claimStore)  at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart(HttpApplication
>   application, HttpContext context, IClaimStore claimStore, ISet`1
>   templateReadOnlyClaims, ISet`1 templateImmutableClaims, ISet`1
>   templateSessionScopeClaims, Boolean dispatchOdataRequest)

Any ideas?

the headers of the request that causes the issue:

> POST http://localhost:55507/ReportViewerWebForm.aspx HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   localhost:55507 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 17325 Origin:
>   http://localhost:55507 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Cache-Control:
>   no-cache X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36 Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 Accept: */* Referer:
>   http://localhost:55507/ReportViewerWebForm.aspx Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8 Cookie: .........
>
> ScriptManager1=ScriptManager1%7CReportViewer1%24ctl13%24ReportControl
>   &__EVENTTARGET=ReportViewer1%24ctl13%24ReportControl &__EVENTARGUMENT=
>   &__LASTFOCUS= &__VIEWSTATE=...... &__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=4C160F9C
>   &__EVENTVALIDATION=........ &__ASYNCPOST=true&
>   &__EVENTTARGET=ReportViewer1%24ctl13%24ReportControl &__EVENTARGUMENT=
>   &__LASTFOCUS= &__VIEWSTATE=...... &__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=4C160F9C
>   &__EVENTVALIDATION=........ &__ASYNCPOST=true&

Comment: How does the HTTP request which causes this error look?

Comment: Updated the the post

Comment: I don’t see any obvious problem in the request. Please contact SDL Customer Support (this seems to be an issue with the ADF).